# Trace Create and Change in Flask Models

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have developed an application in flask. I want to trace create and change. For admin I'm using flask-admin:

```
class MyModelAdmin(ModelView):

    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):

       history = HistoryModel(
          ..
          ..
       )
       db.session.add(history)
       db.session.commit()
```

I have History model for save changes:

```
class HistoryModel(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'history'

   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
   user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
   object_type = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
```

I'm not sure that it is the right approach. BTW, how can I trace change and create for save in HistoryModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy provide event listen for you. There is a decorate named `listens_for` in `sqlalchemy.event`. You use it to `listens_for(HistoryModel, "after_insert")` and `listens_for(HistoryModel.date, "set")`. Check the document about [events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/event.html) and [orm events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html).

Answer (score 0):

The extension [SQLAlchemy-continuum](https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/357hqr/implementing_a_changelogversion_control_system_in/) might be a worthwhile option to look into. It versions your model (data)